# How do you set up sync with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, synchronization

Trying to contact the objectBox team. Your 'contact us' form on your site is broken, just tells me to refresh the page.
I am having difficulty finding information on syncing mobile with desktop. Is this possible yet? Does it require a paid account and if so what is the approximate pricing model?
Keith

Comment: you don't need to have anything to ask a question

Comment: I don't think the "Contact us" form of the object box team is a question that someone here can answer, however, if you have some difficulty with the code you can give us more detail in your answer in order to help you in finding a solution!

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a contact request to a third-party entity, not a programming related question as per the help center.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry that you couldn't reach us via the contact form! Thanks for reporting the issue, we have already fixed it.

Our data synchronization solution is called ObjectBox Sync. Please check out this page for more info: https://objectbox.io/sync/. Here are the Sync Docs: https://sync.objectbox.io/. If there will be any more problems with the form, you can also reach out via contact[at]objectbox.io to request a free trial and discuss this further.

Comment: I too have tried to have contacted you guys... But no one gets back.

Comment: We're sorry that you couldn't reach out to us. Could you please tell how exactly did you try to contact us? (e.g. which page on the website did you use to submit a form request; when did that happen?) 
Looking forward to your answer and hoping we can resolve your issue soon!